# Buffer Writer overriding at everyline

Tags: android, file, file-io, bufferedwriter

I have set up a loop for a buffered writer to write an  array of strings into a file, seems simple enough right? Well for some reason, and I'm sure I'll feel stupid for missing it but it writes over the previous line of text at each iteration.

The following is the loop

```
    for(int i = 0; listnames.length > i; i++){
    String[] data = getItemsandAisles(listnames[i]);
    for(int x = 0; data.length > x; x ++){
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(listfile[i]));
        System.out.println("Writing " + data[x] + " to file " + listfile[i].getAbsolutePath());
        bw.write(data[x]);
        bw.flush();
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

This is the log cat for all of the outputs that I put in, this is just of the first iteration because it has the most items

```
Writing COFFEE CREAMERS 5 to file /data/data/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/files/sample list.txt
Writing SAUCES APPLE CRANBERRY 6 to file /data/data/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/files/sample list.txt
Writing COCOA 5 to file /data/data/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/files/sample list.txt
Writing UMBRELLAS Front End Rack to file /data/data/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/files/sample list.txt
Writing PET NEEDS 9A\/B to file /data/data/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/files/sample list.txt
Writing ITALIAN CHEESE 17 to file /data/data/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/files/sample list.txt
Writing EGGS Dairy to file /data/data/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/files/sample list.txt
Writing BACON Meat to file /data/data/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/files/sample list.txt
```

and then the final output when I download the txt file from the device is just one line of

```
BACON Meat
```

This is what lead me to believe that it was not actually creating a new line. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know that some-what similar questions are on here but I tried all of those solutions but they don't seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open the file before the second loop like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; listnames.length > i; i++){
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(listfile[i]));
    String[] data = getItemsandAisles(listnames[i]);
    for(int x = 0; data.length > x; x ++){
        System.out.println("Writing " + data[x] + " to file " + listfile[i].getAbsolutePath());
        bw.write(data[x]);
        bw.newLine();            
        //bw.flush(); --> not necessary here unless you really need the data on the disk "right now"
    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}
```

Or better, perhaps you want to use a `StringBuilder` as follows.

```
for(int i = 0; listnames.length > i; i++){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] data = getItemsandAisles(listnames[i]);
    for(int x = 0; data.length > x; x ++){
        System.out.println("Writing " + data[x] + " to file " + listfile[i].getAbsolutePath());
        sb.append(data[x]).append("\n");
    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(listfile[i]));
    bw.write(sb.toString());
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}
```

However, the purpose of `BufferedWriter` itself is buffering multiple writes into one big write. So, your choice. =)